# Rails validate format with regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

In my rails app, I want to validate input on a string field containing any number of keywords (which could be more than 1 natural language word (e.g. "document number")). To recognize the individual keywords, I am entering them separated by ", " (or get their end by end of string).

For this I use

`validates :keywords, presence: true, format: { with: /((\w+\s?-?\w+)(,|\z))/i, message: "please enter keywords in correct format"}`

**It should allow** the attribute `keywords` (string) to contain: "word1, word2, word3 word4, word5-word6"

**It should not allow** the use of any other pattern. e.g. not "word1; word2;"
It does incorrectly allow "word1; word2"

On rubular, this [regex](http://rubular.com/r/PiogpmV19E) works; yet in my rails app it allows for example "word1; word2" or "word3; word-"

where is my error (got to say am beginner in Ruby and regex)?

Comment: There can be whitespace or hyphen in between 1+ word chars, right?

Comment: Try [`\A(\w+(?:[\s-]\w+)?)(?:,\s(\g<1>))*\z`](http://rubular.com/r/gv89omlYFK).

Comment: yes correct; eg "credit note" or "credit-note" or "credit - note"; but not "credit-"

Comment: Or [`\A(\w+(?:[\s-]*\w+)?)(?:,\s*(\g<1>))*\z`](http://rubular.com/r/6yqcksK8d9)

Comment: in rubular that works; now in my app it does allows for example "word1; word2" but not "word1; word2;". same as before.

Comment: No idea, [`\A(\w+(?:[\s-]*\w+)?)(?:,\s*\g<1>)*\z`](http://rubular.com/r/epioBhMWBa) should not match `"word1; word2"`. Just because there is no `;` in the pattern and the anchors require a full string match.

Comment: been playing with updating etc and now works (no idea why :-( ). Regex is good! Pls add as answer Wiktor then I accept.

Comment: next up is splitting them out to match against extracted_data with regex.union - good training on the swiss army knife in data extraction (kind of start to like it)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to use anchors `\A` and `\z` and modify the pattern to fit that logic as follows:

```
/\A(\w+(?:[\s-]*\w+)?)(?:,\s*\g<1>)*\z/
```

See the [Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/epioBhMWBa)

**Details**:

- `\A`  - start of string
- `(\w+(?:[\s-]*\w+)?)`  - Group 1 capturing:

  - `\w+` - 1 or more word chars
  - `(?:[\s-]*\w+)?` - 1 or 0 sequences of:

    - `[\s-]*` - 0+ whitespaces or `-`
    - `\w+` - 1 or more word chars
- `(?:,\s*\g<1>)*` - 0 or more sequences of:

  - `,\s*` - comma and 0+ whitespaces
  - `\g<1>` - the same pattern as in Group 1
- `\z` - end of string.

Comment: Wiktor, I need to extend the regex to allow "credit note, credit-note, credit note date, credit notes" pattern. i.e. any number of words followed by comma. Have tried now for 2+ hrs but can't find a solution. Help appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, there is a national holidary here in Poland, I was offline. I understand you want to match any number of hyphenated/space-separated words that may be followed with 0+ sequence of a comma+space and  hyphenated/space-separated words. I think all you need is to replace the `?` quantifier in Group 1 with `*`: [`\A(\w+(?:[\s-]*\w+)*)(?:,\s*\g<1>)*\z`](http://rubular.com/r/THMQUTKX0f).